# DSolve and coupled linear first order PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

Does any one know a trick to make `DSolve` find solution to this coupled linear first order PDE system: (these are Cauchy-Riemann PDE equations, but with one of them having one of the dependent variables as well).

```
ClearAll[F1,F2,x,y];

ode1  = D[F1[x,y],y]-D[F2[x,y],x] == 0
ode2  = D[F1[x,y],x]+D[F2[x,y],y] == y  (*y here causes the problem*)

DSolve[{ode1,ode2},{F1[x,y],F2[x,y]},{x,y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This can be solved in Maple:

```
restart;
#infolevel[pdsolve]:=3;
eq1:= diff(F1(x,y),y)-diff(F2(x,y),x) = 0;
eq2:= diff(F1(x,y),x)+diff(F2(x,y),y) = y;
pdsolve({eq1,eq2},{F1(x,y),F2(x,y)});
```

Solution it gives is

```
F1(x, y) = _F1(y-I*x)+_F2(y+I*x)
F2(x, y) = I*_F1(y-I*x)-I*_F2(y+I*x)+(1/2)*y^2+_C1
```

Screen shot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the RHS of the second equation is not `y` but a constant or some other parameter, then Mathematica can now solve it:

```
ClearAll[F1,F2,x,y,m];
ode1  =  D[F1[x,y],y]-D[F2[x,y],x]  == 0
ode2  = D[F1[x,y],x]+D[F2[x,y],y]   == m
DSolve[{ode1,ode2},{F1[x,y],F2[x,y]},{x,y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a known limitation of `DSolve` or is there a trick or some other method to get the same solution as in Maple?

Using version 11.2 on windows 7.

Comment: Would you view `Simplify[Unevaluated[D[F1[x, y], x] + D[F2[x, y], y] == y] /. F2[x, y] -> G2[x, y] + y^2/2]` as cheating?

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks, but I am not sure how to use the above trick. I trired `ClearAll[F1,F2,G2,x,y,m];
ode1=D[F1[x,y],y]-D[F2[x,y],x]==0;
ode2=Simplify[Unevaluated[D[F1[x,y],x]+D[F2[x,y],y]==y]/.F2[x,y]->G2[x,y]+y^2/2];
DSolve[{ode1,ode2},{F1[x,y],G2[x,y]},{x,y}]` but it still does not solve it.

Comment: Below is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following substitution eliminates the right side of ode2, and DSolve then can solve the resulting equations.

```
ode3 = Unevaluated[D[F1[x, y], y] - D[F2[x, y], x] == 0] /. F2[x, y] -> G2[x, y] + y^2/2
(* D[F1[x, y], y] - D[G2[x, y], x] == 0 *)

ode4 = Simplify[Unevaluated[D[F1[x, y], x] + D[F2[x, y], y] == y] /. 
    F2[x, y] -> G2[x, y] + y^2/2]
(* D[F1[x, y], x] + D[G2[x, y], y] == 0 *)

DSolve[{ode3, ode4}, {F1[x, y], G2[x, y]}, {x, y}] // Flatten
(* {F1[x, y] -> I C[1][I x + y] - I C[2][-I x + y], 
    G2[x, y] -> C[1][I x + y] + C[2][-I x + y]} *)
```